# How to match EAAccessory and CBPeripheral with MFi device?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, mfi, eaaccessory

I have MFi device which uses BLE for control and Classic Bluetooth for audio streaming.

In the App, i use coreBluetooth framework to scan BLE and EAAccessory framework to scan Classic Bluetooth. 
I don't want the BLE of target device to be connected if its Classic Bluetooth is not yet connected. **So i need to know which EAAccessory is corresponding to target CBPeripheral.**

I am familiar with coreBluetooth, there is UUID string to identify the CBPeripheral. But it looks not exist in EAAccessory. 
I have an idea but not sure: maybe firmware side can config **EAAccessory's serial number** and **CBPeripheral's manufacture data in advertisement data** with the same 
serial number, so that App side can check if they are the same.

Dose anyone knows the general way to implement this in App side and firmware side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really do not think there is s relationship between the 2. BT and BTLE are managed by different chip at peripheral side and phone side.
Usually in BT you use the MAC address to identify the peripheral on BTLE side the MAC address is not used anymore since iOS at the first connection give its own identifier to the peripheral.
What you can do is probably at firmware side, by exposing a service with a characteristic that somehow relate the 2.
**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT**
I see, as far as I know there a best practice doesn't exist.The worst part is that you have to handle connections differently, mostly due to how connection are made on iOS side. While on the BLE you can choose a not encrypted connection that would not require paring or bonding, on BT side I guess that bonding is required.
Probably the most simple flow would be, user bond the BT device. Once you are in the app and detect the connected BT device, use a scan method for detect BLE companion device by filtering for a specific service id that your device exposes, once you do that you can also filter discoveries using BLE name without still making a connection.
Adv packet are restricted in size (29 usable byte) but you can also use the scan response (31 byte), that exposes some additional properties such as manufacturer data that will be exposed in a dictionary (`kCBAdvDataManufacturerData`).
Once you know that is the correct device you can start a connection, that does not require pair or bond but is NOT encrypted (Pair and Bond will require the user to accept the connection inside your app).

Comment: Thanks Andrea, i also think it probably should be first implemented at firmware side (config with specific "manufacture data" or other methods). I want to know what is the general way to do this. Let me update the question.